# Design rationale behind that separate acceptor class exists in ASIO

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, asio

I'm trying to understand why does ASIO have a dedicated `tcp::acceptor` class.

Under the hood, both `tcp::acceptor` and `tcp::socket` contain an `int socket_fd`, don't they?

Why not just add `tcp::acceptor`'s unique functions into `tcp::socket`? `tcp::socket` can do anything which can be done by the low-level `int socket_fd`, except `listen` & `accept`.

(I am new to ASIO, maybe I don't see something fundamental)

Comment: Because one usually have passive (accepting and listening) sockets separate. You can't really read from them or write to them, only accept new connections.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: could it be the only reason? Using this principle, ASIO should have a `tcp::connector` too. Because connecting an already connected socket is meaningless. So we should take out `connect` from `socket`.

Comment: But you can still use a connected socket to read and write. In fact that's how you usually *use* sockets from a client: You create the socket, connect it somewhere, and read and write from and to it. A "connector" is just a plain non-passive socket.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: yes, but you cannot connect it :) For acceptors, read/write is meaningless. For connected sockets, connect is meaningless. For me, these cases are the same. (so, if we use this principle, the clean design would be: acceptor, connector, connected_socket). I'm not nitpicking, I'd like to understand the design of this. If this is the only reason what you've said, it's OK.

Comment: I don't really see the need for a `connector`. What would it do? Connect to an acceptor and then return a new `connected_socket`? Why? The `connector` and the `connected_socket` would just be the same (or reference the same underlying raw socket). Connecting doesn't create a new socket.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I know, now I see things conceptually. If acceptor exists, because read/write is meaningless for it, then connector should exist, as connect is meaningless for a connected socket. In an implementation, connector would just register connection parameters, and its connect function would create a socket, connect it, and then return a `connected_socket`. Yes, from an implementation viewpoint this is not "logical", but from a user who uses these classes, it can be.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: or even, there could be a static connector function, which creates a `connected_socket`, if it is more logical. Anyways, thanks for the discussion

Comment: Okay, I see your point better now.And yes having some kind of factory class to create connections and return sockets with a specific set of options might make sense I guess. At least if one need to create many connections using the same options.

Comment: @geza In this comment you're comparing a logical distinction on purpose (connection socket vs. listening socket) to distinction in lifecycle/state (connected vs. unconnected socket). That's apples and pears, and even so it's the library designer's choice what kind of abstraction they want to model. You could technically have `basic_connected_socket<...> connect(unconnected_socket<...>& s)` if you want.

Comment: @sehe, yes, it's true. From the BSD viewpoint server/client sockets are the same. So it is a lifecycle issue. You can create a socket, listen, accept, then close it, and reuse it as a client socket with connect. So the question is: why is a logical distinction between acceptor and socket? But I see your answer now :)

Comment: It's merely the handle type representing them is the same (technical argument). There's a difference between a socket which can never be accepted from or a socket which may become (dis)connected (again). Again, it's about modeling abstractions: `acceptor.accept(socket&, ...)` is fundamentally more expressive than `acceptor.accept(int fd, ...)` and indeed `acceptor.accept(acceptor&, ...)` makes no sense. It's just a more rich API interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have a separate set of operations.

Also, they have a separate set of socket options that apply, e.g.

```
acceptor_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
```

This distinction raises the abstraction of the interface and makes it easier to use the API correctly.

> To put it bluntly, you could say it's because it's a C++ API, not BSD sockets.

It's the same answer you'd get when you'd have asked why `socket` was made an object with methods (instead of just passing the handle around, much simpler really?). Or why the classes are all templated on the protocol (remember casts like `(struct sockaddr_in *) p->ai_addr`? You'll see the merit).