# What does it mean to "open" an acceptor?

Tags: c++, networking, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

In boost.asio, there is a class called an [`acceptor`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/acceptor.html). The `acceptor` is used to listen for connection requests on a specific endpoint and open a socket in response to a request.

There are three `acceptor` constructors I am interested in.

1. construct an `acceptor` without opening or binding

```
explicit basic_socket_acceptor(
    const executor_type & ex);
```

2. construct an `acceptor` and open it

```
basic_socket_acceptor(
    const executor_type & ex,
    const protocol_type & protocol);
```

3. construct an `acceptor`, open it, and bind it to an endpoint

```
basic_socket_acceptor(
    const executor_type & ex,
    const endpoint_type & endpoint,
    bool reuse_addr = true);
```

1 and 3 both make sense. 1 constructs the acceptor in the `C++` sense: allocate memory on the stack, maybe initialize some variables, etc. 3 specifies the endpoint that the acceptor should listen on. Incoming connection requests addressed to the endpoint will be accepted and a connection will be created on a new socket. 2, however, appears to be a middle ground that allows you to set a "protocol type."

I want to say that that "2 allows you to specify more member variables (the protocol) than 1 and less member variables (e.g., IP address and port number) than 3." However, I don't know if it does anything "extra" over setting some member variables (does it engage with the OS or the NIC?).

What does it mean to open an acceptor?

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/open.html

Comment: opens the socket!

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I'm not sure what that member function does either. If I had to guess, I would guess you are just setting some member variables.

Comment: I chose to talk about the constructor to differentiate between 1, 2, and 3. A question about the member function ```open``` would probably have the same answer as this question.

Answer (score 3):

It opens the socket, indeed.

> I chose to talk about the constructor to differentiate between 1, 2, and 3. A question about the member function open would probably have the same answer as this question.

The question then becomes just what does `::socket` do (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/socket.html):

> The socket() function shall create an unbound socket in a communications domain, and return a file descriptor that can be used in later function calls that operate on sockets

So for your practical understanding, it allocates and initializes in-kernel resources[1].

**Note**

Technically there is no difference between an "acceptor" socket and a "connection" socket. Asio distinguishes them conceptually so it's easier to use them right. The reverse question might offer enlightenment: [Design rationale behind that separate acceptor class exists in ASIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525643/design-rationale-behind-that-separate-acceptor-class-exists-in-asio/46527111#46527111)

[1] on most operating systems, userland TCP stacks exists though

Comment: +1 but: it's not clear what you meant by "the socket." I have deduced from the answers that the acceptor requires its own socket, and this is the socket you open with ```open```. This answer could be improved by adding that the ```acceptor``` needs its own socket. Perhaps that is obvious, but if I had realized it, I wouldn't have posted this question.

Comment: Yes. Accceptors _are_ sockets. Technically there is no difference between an "acceptor" socket and a "connection" socket. Asio distinguishes them conceptually so it's easier to use them right. The reverse question might lead to enlightenment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525643/design-rationale-behind-that-separate-acceptor-class-exists-in-asio/46527111#46527111

Comment: Well, asio needs to know it should call `listen()` on some sockets and not others. This has to be expressed in either the type system or in a member variable, and the type system is a reasonable choice.

Comment: I think it's more about the user who needs to know, and Asio does a nice job of helping the user. The BSD sockets API is a bit unwieldy in the regard that every operation is just available on every socket, just leading to errors or unspecified behaviour when misused.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the underlying logic of accepting incoming networking connections with BSD sockets?

The steps, if you write them manually, are:

1. *open* a socket with `socket()`

   just like opening a file, and you get an integer descriptor you can use with `read()`, `write()`, `close()` etc.
2. *bind* the socket to a network address with `bind()`

   unlike a file, the socket descriptor is not associated with anything outside your process until you do this
3. tell the OS you want to listen for connections on this socket, with `listen()`

   until this point, it could still be used as an *outgoing* connection, although it's unusual to bind the source address explicitly
4. start accepting incoming connection requests by calling `accept()`

So when you *open* an acceptor, you're asking the OS for a socket *and* saving the descriptor to a member variable.

When you *bind* an acceptor, you're just asking the OS to link that socket to an address (but there may be a member variable tracking its state as well, so the acceptor remembers this has been done).

Note that the "middle ground" passes a protocol type, which is needed to *open* a socket (it corresponds exactly to the arguments to `socket()`), but it doesn't have an address (or endpoint), so it can't *bind* that socket yet.