# Boost asio - is it possible to reuse a socket?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, asio

After I:

- created a tcp-socket
- put it in listening
- received an Incoming "message" from the Client
- "processed" the incoming accomplice and closed the socket...

Whether that it is possible to put this socket on listening again? Experiment shows that no - the accept() function - throws an error.

Is it possible, somehow, to "reset" a closed socket to its original state? In order not to release the previously allocated memory for this socket and not to create a new socket, which in the end will also have to be deleted.

PS:

```
my_socket_p = new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(io_context);
my_acceptor.accept(my_socket_p );
```

Comment: You need to `open()` after `close()` in case you want to continue using the instance. Honestly, you don't really save anything by not creating a new socket.

Comment: @ALX23z, thnak you, won't I save on new/delete calls ?

Comment: `new/delete` on such small objects are inconsequential compared to any socketing. And while I don't know details of the implementation, I don't believe `boost::socket` uses any `new/delete` operations in creation or destruction. If you allocate the socket on a heap that's a different story.

Comment: @ALX23z, why boost::socket ? To create a new socket for a new client, I allocate memory for this new socket, and when the Client disconnects, I close the socket and free the memory previously allocated.

Comment: You wrote in tags `boost-asio` and `asio` thus I presume you use `boost::socket`. I mean `boost:: ... ::socket` don't remember all the namespaces in between.

Comment: @ALX23z, as I wrote - to create a boost::socket, you need to allocate memory for it, and then release it.

Comment: @ALX23z you don't save much, but the code is simpler and it avoid allocations (and the associated errors). I've written a proper example with example code.

Answer (score 1):

The socket you put in listening mode is typically **not** the socket that you close when you're done handling a request.

> *Asio makes this distinction more explicit than in the underlying sockets API. I discussed this before here: [Design rationale behind that separate acceptor class exists in ASIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525643/design-rationale-behind-that-separate-acceptor-class-exists-in-asio/46527111#46527111) (see also e.g. [What does it mean to "open" an acceptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73076962/what-does-it-mean-to-open-an-acceptor/73078662#73078662)).*

Simple example of a typical server that accepts requests and echoes them back reversed:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8109ec33a3e7849)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;

    // listen on port 7878
    tcp::acceptor acc(ioc, {{}, 7878});
    acc.listen();

    while (true) {
        tcp::socket conn = acc.accept();
        auto        peer   = conn.remote_endpoint();

        try {
            std::string request;
            read_until(conn, asio::dynamic_buffer(request), "\n");

            reverse(begin(request), end(request) - 1); // reverse until line-end
            write(conn, asio::buffer("reversed: " + request));
            conn.close();
        } catch(boost::system::system_error const& se) {
            std::cerr << "Error with peer " << peer << ": " << se.code().message() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

With example clients:

```
netcat 127.0.0.1 7878 <<< "Hello world!"
netcat 127.0.0.1 7878 <<< "Bye world!"
```

Prints

```
reversed: !dlrow olleH
reversed: !dlrow eyB
```

### Re-using?

There are other overloads of `accept` that take a socket by reference, and yes they can be re-used:

```
tcp::socket conn(ioc); // reused

while (true) {
    acc.accept(conn);
    auto peer = conn.remote_endpoint();
```

With the rest of the code un-changed: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd86d92156cd84dd)**

### More Typical

More typically code would be asynchronous and the "connection handling" would be in some other class, e.g. `Session`. In such cases `conn` would be **moved** into `Session`. This is also explicitly documented as proper use, [e.g.](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket/operator_eq_/overload1.html#:%7E:text=Following%20the%20move%2C%20the%20moved%2Dfrom%20object%20is%20in%20the%20same%20state%20as%20if%20constructed%20using%20the%20basic_socket(const%20executor_type%26)%20constructor):

> Following the move, the moved-from object is in the same state as if constructed using the basic_socket(const executor_type&) constructor.

So, you could write the code as such:

```
tcp::socket conn(ioc); // reused

while (true) {
    acc.accept(conn);
    std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(conn))->run();
}
```

You can see it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/390d8ab4c2bb24bf)** again, although I'll include the far more idiomatic version using the move-accept handler overload of `async_accept` instead here:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14d88cd57674843e)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;

struct Session : std::enable_shared_from_this<Session> {
    Session(tcp::socket s) : conn_(std::move(s)) {}

    void run() { do_reverse_echo(); }

  private:
    void do_reverse_echo() {
        async_read_until( //
            conn_, asio::dynamic_buffer(buffer_), "\n",
            [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t) {
                if (ec) {
                    std::cerr << "Error with peer " << peer_ << ": " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                    return;
                }

                reverse(begin(buffer_), end(buffer_) - 1); // reverse until line-end
                buffer_ = "reversed: " + buffer_;
                async_write(conn_, asio::buffer(buffer_), asio::detached);
            });
    }

    tcp::socket   conn_;
    tcp::endpoint peer_{conn_.remote_endpoint()};
    std::string   buffer_;
};

struct Listener {
    Listener(asio::any_io_executor ex, uint16_t port) : acc(ex, {{}, port}) {
        acc.listen();
        accept_loop();
    }

  private:
    tcp::acceptor acc;

    void accept_loop() {
        acc.async_accept([this](error_code ec, tcp::socket conn) {
            if (ec) {
                std::cerr << "Stopping listener: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                return;
            }

            accept_loop();
            std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(conn))->run();
        });
    }
};

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;

    Listener s(ioc.get_executor(), 7878);

    ioc.run();
}
```

Still with the same output, obviously.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the accept function explicitly specifying the created socket.